# Running lsp-mode with Python using the pyls from the virtualenv of my project

Tags: python, virtualenv, lsp-mode

I wish to run LSP using the pyls from the virtualenv of my project.

I don't have pyls installed globally (only in the local virtualenv).

I found this snippet online:

```lisp
  (lsp-define-stdio-client lsp-python "python"
                           #'projectile-project-root
                           '("pyls"))
```

However the function `lsp-define-stdio-client` has been deprecated.

I can enable lsp with `python-mode`, and when opening a python file, I get a message saying `LSP :: No LSP server running for python-mode` (which is expected), then run:

```lisp
(lsp-register-client
 (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection "/path/to/my/project/bin/pyls")
          :major-modes '(python-mode)
          :server-id 'pyls))
```

And finally run `lsp` from the buffer containing the python file.

However I would like this to be done automatically (when I open a python file, emacs finds the corresponding pyls and runs it).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`lsp-stdio-connection` accepths also a function so you may replace `(lsp-stdio-connection "/path/to/my/project/bin/pyls")` with

```
 (lsp-stdio-connection 
   (lambda () 
     ;; implementation of the function that returns the proper 
     ;; pyls for the current directory/project/file.
     ))
```

Alternatively, you may use define `.dir-locals.el` `lsp-pyls-server-command` in each project(refer to `lsp-mode` [FAQ](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/faq/) for an example).